# Creating a HTML element in the back-end instead of the front-end

Tags: javascript, dom, server

I'm trying to create a span element on the server before serving it to the client rather than on the front-end. However, I got the following error.

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

The relevant code in the back-end.

```
    let words = story.split(/([\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}']+)/gu);

    for(let i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        if(!/[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}']+/.test(words[i])){
            let span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = words[i];
            console.log(span);
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it that creating HTML elements can only be done on the front end?

Comment: There is no dom on the backend, you need a tool such as [jsDom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to do this. Otherwise just build the string instead of building dom elements.

Comment: The code seems fine, but you're only outputting to the console. Try document.write()

Comment: @ symlink the error occurs at this line `let span = document.createElement('span');` so event if I add a `document.write()` statement below, I would be getting the same error. I think "Get Off My Lawn" is correct.

Comment: You must consider that the server and client are different platforms that communicate via a protocol named HTTP. That protocol is designed for one primary mission - to send **text** from the server to the client and visa versa. With that understanding, you now know your server should send only text since there is no way to send a DOM element.